# Strange ListView with UIL Refreshing Issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

The ListView always shows different pictures as soon as the pictures get into the view, and then change back to the correct pictures.
I do understand the view is recycling, but why it is doing this?

Neither Gallery app or QuickPic app has this behavior.  This app is quick loading and doesn't consume a lot of memory either.

What's going on???  How do I make it perform like QuickPic or Gallery?

Adapter class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {       
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, parent, false);

          viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.GridViewImage); 
          convertView.setTag(viewHolder);            
      } 
      else
      {  
          viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
      }

      GridViewImageLoader.getImageLoader(mContext).displayImage(getItem(position).getImageUrl(), viewHolder.imageView);


      return convertView;
    }
```

ImageLoader class:

```
public class GridViewImageLoader {

    private GridViewImageLoader(){   }

    public static ImageLoader getImageLoader(Context context){
        try {
            if (ImageLoader.getInstance().isInited()) {
                return ImageLoader.getInstance();
            }
            DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.automatic_icon)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) // default
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) // default
//            .decodingOptions()
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()) // default
            .handler(new Handler()) // default
            .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).build();

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
            return ImageLoader.getInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(0);
```

right before you call:

```
GridViewImageLoader.getImageLoader(mContext).displayImage(getItem(position).getImageUrl(), viewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue is still the same.  It shows different pictures first, then change to the correct pictures whenever it gets in the view.  Thanks